# Zero or Decimal as User Input?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a unit converter written in Visual Basic, using Visual Studio 2013. The program is working fine until the user enters a zero(0) or starts with a decimal(.). I get this error message: Conversion from string "" to type 'Decimal' is not valid. How can I get this program to accept zero and/or a decimal point as the initial input from the user without the program crashing? Code is below.

```
Private Function GetLength1(ByVal decLengthUnit1 As Decimal) As Decimal

    Dim decResult1 As Decimal

    If cboUnitType.SelectedItem = "Length" Then

        ' converts kilometer to...
        If cbo1.SelectedItem = "Kilometer" Then
            If cbo2.SelectedItem = "Kilometer" Then
                decResult1 = txtUnit1.Text
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Meter" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 1000)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Centimeter" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 100000)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Millimeter" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 1000000)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Mile" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 0.621371191)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Yard" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 1093.613297)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Foot" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 3280.83989)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Inch" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 39370.07868)
            End If
        End If
    End If

    If decResult1 < 0 Then
        txtUnit2.ForeColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf decResult1 >= 0 Then
        txtUnit2.ForeColor = Color.Green
    End If

    Return decResult1.ToString().Trim("0")
End Function


Private Sub txtUnit1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtUnit1.TextChanged

    If suppressTextBox1TextChanged = False Then

        ' convert string to numeric data type
        Decimal.TryParse(txtUnit1.Text, decUnit1)

        ' handle String.Empty, or negative sign
        If txtUnit1.Text = "" OrElse txtUnit1.Text = "-" Then
            txtUnit2.Text = ""

        ElseIf cboUnitType.SelectedItem = "Length" Then
            suppressTextBox2TextChanged = True
            txtUnit2.Text = GetLength1(decUnit1)
            suppressTextBox2TextChanged = False

        ElseIf cboUnitType.SelectedItem = "Pressure" Then


        ElseIf cboUnitType.SelectedItem = "Temperature" Then
            suppressTextBox2TextChanged = True
            txtUnit2.Text = GetTemp1(decUnit1)
            suppressTextBox2TextChanged = False

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Convert.ToDecimal()` instead of just assigning the text box value to the `Decimal` variable, like this:

```
decResult1 = Convert.ToDecimal(txtUnit1.Text)
```

---

As Ahmed pointed out in the comments, using `Decimal.TryParse()` will allow you to avoid the exception that `System.Convert.ToDecimal()` will throw if the cast fails, like this:

```
Dim number As Decimal

If Decimal.TryParse(txtUnit1.Text, number) Then
    ' Successfully cast text box text to a Decimal
Else
    ' Unable to cast text box text to a Decimal      
End If
```

UPDATE:

Here is your code edited:

```
Private Function GetLength1(ByVal decLengthUnit1 As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim decResult1 As Decimal

    If cboUnitType.SelectedItem = "Length" Then
        ' converts kilometer to...
        If cbo1.SelectedItem = "Kilometer" Then
            If cbo2.SelectedItem = "Kilometer" Then
                Decimal.TryParse(txtUnit1.Text, decResult1)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Meter" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 1000)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Centimeter" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 100000)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Millimeter" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 1000000)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Mile" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 0.621371191)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Yard" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 1093.613297)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Foot" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 3280.83989)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Inch" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 39370.07868)
            End If
        End If
    End If

    If decResult1 < 0 Then
        txtUnit2.ForeColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf decResult1 >= 0 Then
        txtUnit2.ForeColor = Color.Green
    End If

    Return decResult1.ToString().Trim("0")
End Function
```

Comment: just to add - use the TryParse method to see if it parses successfully rather than throwing an exception if it cannot parse it (such as the input not being a decimal input but a text/literal input instead like "abc123")

Comment: Would I be using this in the GetLength1() Function, or in the TextChanged event? decResult1 = Convert.ToDecimal(txtUnit1.Text)

Comment: @Zack - `GetLength1()`

Comment: @KarlAnderson - I am having trouble understanding your advice. Could you please edit my code and post it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @KarlAnderson - Thanks for the update. Unfortunately, that first line was for the instance that the user chose the same units on both sides to be converted. Like they chose kilometers to be converted to kilometers. I did it like that so it would just equal the user input.